# Why vote down if the answer IS constructive?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I've recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599992/544283) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421242/no-fixed-height-header-content-fills-rest-of-page-with-auto-vertical-overflow) which, in fact, resolves the OP's request, with one exception:

> I am looking for a non JS solution.

My answer clearly states this: (and resolves the OP's need - view full [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599992/544283) for more details)

> I don't think it's possible w/o using any javascript

So why and how is my answer not constructive to gain a vote down?

My thoughts are:

- IF the user who answered has less than X rep then vote down.
- ARE this site's users chasing badges more than helping each other?
- IS the community being far less tolerant than a year ago?

I'm not saying everybody are the same, but some users maybe don't read/know/think enough to give a down vote. This is just a strange behavior I've seen more times than I would like to, this is nothing personal, just a general question about the community behavior. I've seen this things far more too often.

It's very annoying since I was trying to help a user, spent time, uploaded screenshots to give what I believe is a complete solid answer regarding css and jquery and got down-voted for nothing. I'd like to believe I'm not the only one mad at this situation, and I DO know nobody forced me to answer or help, I did it on my own will, and the user who down-voted me did it as well, it's just a topic to see if other users are experiencing the same, this site has helped me out more times than I could possibly count, about a year ago I decided to make myself a user to help when I can, and this is just unfair.

Note: I don't give a sh*t about a down-vote, but I want to know, as I've said if other users are noticing the same things.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you missed the part before that. The full statement is: *"I use JqueryUI to make it re-sizable, but I am looking for a non JS solution."* It seems to me that the OP already has a working JS solution, so why would he want to receive yet another JS solution?

Comment: It's just one down vote. They happen. Don't sweat it at all.

Comment: @animuson because the OP's solution don't even do what he wanted, I mean, it's close, but it does not solves his requirement.

Comment: Not always, but at times it seems to me that high rep user's love to downvote other user's answers just because it was better than theirs.

Comment: Anonymous downvotes are a fact of life. And, as the down-voter in question, I would like to state for the record it was pretty much for the same reason animuson mentioned in an earlier comment here. I did go back and mention this on the answer, however. (Also the assertion there is no non-JS answer is wrong because one of the solutions posted clearly works ... with only CSS.)

Comment: @Xarcell: That sounds like an accusation which should be backed up by evidence. I suspect it *does* happen very occasionally - but by both high-rep and low-rep users. Also bear in mind that just because *you* think your answer is better than someone else's doesn't mean they share that opinion.

Comment: related: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/165773) "...trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y..."

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm not even talking about me, It's never happened to me, but I've seen it happen to other people. If I come across it again, I'll be sure to let you know.

Comment: @Xarcell: How would you know that it had happened? Unless the user involved actually says that they're downvoting *because the answer is better than theirs* you're just guessing at their motives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you were thoughtfully trying to be helpful, your statement that it couldn't be done with JavaScript outright may have just caught someone's eye, who decided to downvote without reading your actual answer. It's possible that if you had backed up with a reason why it couldn't be done, they may have just left you alone.

Your assertion does seem to be backed up by [Feantury's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554109/697560) and comments, who after trying for a while came up with essentially what you suggested. It's probable the downvoter didn't spend much time reading anything else.

You posted a good answer. Even if it's not something that the OP wanted, it's likely that you'll help someone in the future, so you get a +1 from me.

Comment: I think you're right, and I'm not CSS ninja, but I could say I'm pretty good at it, so maybe there is NO answer without javascript because of the calculations, since CSS is not meant for that. On the other hand, I see your point, maybe I started it wrong, as I said, I don't care about the down vote. In short: thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not saying everybody are the same, but some users maybe don't
>   read/know/think enough to give a down vote.
>
> - IF the user who answered has less than X rep then vote down.
> - ARE this site's users chasing badges more than helping each other?
> - IS the community being far less tolerant than a year ago?

In some cases, you are absolutely correct. People can be jerks. Sometimes downvotes aren't warranted. Sometimes they are indisputably warranted. But most times they are a matter of opinion.

It's a risk you take whenever you post a question or an answer. But you do have another avenue available: **You can post a comment.** That's probably the number one reason for comments; you can help the OP and yourself to better understand the question.

> It's very annoying since I was trying to help a user, spent time,
>   uploaded screenshots to give what I believe is a complete solid answer
>   regarding css and jquery and got down-voted for nothing.

Thank you for spending time to improve the community. I sincerely mean that, as someone who gets a great deal of good information from SO. However:

1. The OP clearly stated that they didn't want JS.
2. You could have clarified this with a comment before spending (possibly wasting) your time on it.
3. I'm pretty sure that your assertion in your answer is wrong.
4. That makes your answer potentially misleading, and at minimum clutters up the question.

I spent some time investigating #3, i.e. whether or not there is a pure CSS solution.

I'm not sure that I have the approach the OP wants, so I took my own advice. I [posted 3 comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421242/no-fixed-height-header-content-fills-rest-of-page-with-auto-vertical-overflow#comment23864697_16421242) with potential options and I'll wait for clarification. If those suggestions help, great. I may expand one into an answer, or I might just move on. Feel free to pull something useful from them and update your answer.

There is no hard and fast rule, but *in general* I find it to be good community manners to ask a clarifying question if you are going to pose an answer that is contrary to what the OP requests. Again, you are free to do as you wish, and others are free to downvote if they feel it was not helpful.

Lastly—on the topic of manners—your meta question comes across as borderline rude/accusatory. A downvote can sting (especially when you feel you are right and have put time into the answer) but it doesn't mean that the general tenor of the community is negative. Just food for thought.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, thank you very much for your tips, especially `clarified this with a comment` **before** `spending`. Regarding `comes across as borderline rude/accusatory` yes, it's true, but it was just a feeling I've got. Ill remove the question. But THANK you for your comment.